# Error in phonegap:Cannot find module '..\..\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib'

Tags: cordova

There are several errors when I install phonegap using

```
npm install -g phonegap.
```

Nevertheleess it ends. When I type phonegap, I have this error signal:

> Cannot find module '....\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib'

Please help.